# Vuex Store, Как получить доступ к state модуля из другого модуля?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-cli

У меня есть несколько vuex модулей, из которых нужно получить доступ к данным в  определенном компоненте Vuex. В документации Vuex я видел пример с использованием rootState, но не смог повторить такое. Как можно реализовать что-то подобное? Меня устроит как вариант с обьявлением данных в родительском компоненте, так и в дочернем. Как пример :

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
         SharedData : []
}
modules : {ModuleA,ModuleB};
```

ModuleA

```
mutations : {
    changeSharedData(state,newData) {
           SharedData = newData;
    }
}
```

ModuleB

```
 mutations : {
        getSharedData(state) {
              state.someLocalData = SharedData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module A:

```
const moduleA = {
    namespaced: true,
    mutations : {
        changeStr(state, newData) {
          state.str = newData
          console.log(state.str)
        }
    }
}
```

Root store:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        str: ''
    }, 
    modules: {
        a: moduleA
    }
})
```

From component:

```
this.$store.commit('a/changeStr', 'change store from module')
```

Comment: Спасибо! Можно еще вопрос? Как будет правильнее разбивать на модули? К примеру, у меня есть общий массив, и мутации добавления данных, удаления данных, обновления данных в определенном элементе массива,сохранения данных в localstorage и т.д. Лучше вынести сам массив и все мутации, относящиеся к нему, в один модуль, или вынести массив в родительский store и разбить мутации на разные модули, в зависимости от того, что они выполняют?

Comment: Нет, если вся логика относится к одному массиву, то это все должно быть в одном модуле. Модули можно использовать если есть совершенно разные сущности и логика